Why was the term "isomorphism" chosen in category theory?
Coming to category theory from elsewhere in mathematics we learn that the term isomorphism is used to mean any morphism with a 2-sided inverse. Thus it seems to be analogous to the already familiar notion of bijection, rather than the stricter notion of structure-preserving bijection. (And, after all, isomorphism was constructed from the Greek for same and structure.)
I have a rough appreciation for the idea of concrete categories, and for the fact that not every category is concretizable. But why was a term that does imply preservation of structure chosen in the world of categories, where the objects in general have no internal structure at all, and thus no structure to preserve?

Isomorphism is a concept and term that predates category theory. In fact Eilenberg and Mac Lane's motivation and point of discovery of category theory was very much the question of how to make precise an existing intuitive notion of a group isomorphism being "natural". See both their:

Eilenberg, S., & MacLane, S. (1942). Natural isomorphisms in group
theory. Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences, 28(12),
537-543.

And Mac Lane's autobiographical commentary in Chapter 14 - Naturality of:

Mac Lane, S. (2005). Saunders Mac Lane: a mathematical autobiography.
AK Peters/CRC Press.

A very nice historical excavation of the concept of isomorphism in mathematics can be found in:

Timmermans, B. (2012). Prehistory of the Concept of Mathematical
Structure: Isomorphism Between Group Theory, Crystallography, and
Philosophy. The Mathematical Intelligencer, 34(3), 41-54.

The concept of isomorphisms of groups was introduced by Camille Jordan in his:

Jordan, C. (1870). Traité des substitutions et des équations
algébriques. Gauthier Villars. p. 54.

but he borrowed the terms (as Timmermans points out) from Bravais's work in crystallography. Incidentally the term was coined to describe invariants of crystallographic structure of different underlying molecular structure by Mitscherlich in 1819, see:

Melhado, E. M. (1980). Mitscherlich's discovery of isomorphism.
Historical studies in the physical sciences, 11(1), 87-123.


Yes, I know that the idea of isomorphism predates category theory. And in its previous usages it refers to preserved structure. But the objects of a category possess no structure (Isn’t that the whole point of cater theory?) So if MacLane & Co. wanted to apply a pre-existing term to something within their new theory, why did they choose the (seemingly) over-narrow one (viz., isomorphism) over something like the (seemingly) more appropriate bijection?

@PaulTanenbaum The notion that an isomorphism is a bijection that preserves structure is very much Mac Lane's own. I don't know of any evidence that he ever contemplated this being problematic. (See Mac Lane (1986) "Mathematics, Form, and Function" Springer, p. 15 for an example of ordered sets with isomorphism as bijection that preserves order structure vs a bijection that do not maintain the given order).

Yes, among others we have order isomorphisms, graph isomorphisms, and group isomorphisms, but they all preserve structure (comparabilities, adjacencies, and group operations, respectively). Consider that given partially ordered sets $P=(X,\leq_1)$ and $Q=(Y,\leq_2)$ on $n$-sets $X$ and $Y$, there are $n!$ bijections from $X$ to $Y$, but for instance if $|\leq_1| \neq |\leq_2|$, then none of them will be an order isomorphism. So, is there some structure that is always preserved by every category isomorphism?

@PaulTanenbaum Mac Lane did contemplate the usefulness of isomorphism of categories in his (1997) Categories for the Working Mathematician, Springer, p. 92f and suggested "There is a more general (and more useful) notion: [..] an equivalence of categories". In general you may notice that I try to answer questions about history. I really am not trying to discuss mathematics itself here. For that you may want seek out SE:Mathematics or SE:MO.
